# why is my vscode (macOS) showing 5k changes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Pardon me for a simple question.

I have a git project located at `~/Documents/gitproject/gitproject.github.io`.

When I open the project folder in VSCode. It looks fine. But when I open a file in another folder, VSCode shows 5k changes.

[image]

I added an item to the `settings.json` file:

```
    "git.path": "/Users/username/Documents/gitproject/gitproject.github.io",
```

I thought this might make a difference, but, no, it still shows 5k changes.

I want VSCode to show only changes made in the `gitproject` folder, and not everything in my `username` folder. How to do that?

Comment: Could it be different line endings?

Comment: You have created a git repository in `~`. Destroy the `~/.git` directory to get rid of it, and create a new one in `gitproject.github.io`.

Comment: The `"git.path"` is for setting a path to `git.exe`, not to a repo. You don't need it.

Comment: Thanks, @HolyBlackCat. You're right on! I'm very new to git. I did not know what I did. I deleted `~/.git` and all 5k changes are gone. I also realized my misunderstanding about the `"git.path"` after posting the question. Thanks for pointing that out as well! Learned something today! Thanks!